# Erro Fatal ao executar a query

Tags: query, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer um while mas não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum. Tá retornando o erro abaixo:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /home2/techlogu/public_html/index.php on line 697

Meu código está assim:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT 
agenda.id_curso, 
agenda.id_pessoa, 
cursos.img, 
pessoas.nick, 
cursos.nome_curso, 
pessoas.nome, 
cursos.conteudo
FROM pessoas 
INNER JOIN cursos 
INNER JOIN agenda ON cursos.id_curso = agenda.id_curso
AND pessoas.id_pessoa = agenda.id_pessoa
ORDER BY RAND()";  

// Executa a consulta OU mostra uma mensagem de erro
$resultado = $MySQLi->query($sql) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error,  E_USER_ERROR);  // Essa é a linha 697 que tá dando erro fatal

while ($dataUser = $resultado->fetch_object()) {

$id_curso   = $dataUser->id_curso;
$id_pessoa  = $dataUser->id_pessoa;
$img        = $dataUser->img;
$nick       = $dataUser->nick;
$nome_curso = $dataUser->nome_curso;
$nome       = $dataUser->nome;
$conteudo   = $dataUser->conteudo;


?>
```

Comment: Boa noite, amigo você ja executou a query em um banco para ver se o resultado ta ok?
outra coisa, a escrita $msqli sua ta certa?
$resultado = **$MySQLi**->query($sql) olha aqui:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá Gilson. Obrigado pela resposta. Já executei a query no PHPMyAdmin e ele trouxe o resultado corretamente. No exemplo que tá no link, não tem WHILE e pelo que eu pude comparar no exemplo da programação orientada a objeto do link que cê me passou, está correto o uso de $MySQLi->query($sql)